# Packet loss while using UDP to fetch Data from Memcached

Tags: networking, tcp, udp, memcached

I have heard, Many companies like facebook are using UDP to fetch data from memcached. I have a doubt, How they make sure there is NO packet loss and order of received packet is per requirement.As we know tcp provide such facility but udp does not.

Comment: You can layer an application protocol on top of UDP that provides reliability to the application.

Comment: @Ron Maupin When We use UDP, Does the MEMCACHED protocol do the job for us OR We need to write an application layer to ensure fetched data is consistent.

Answer (score 0):

OSI Model has 7 layers which are:

1. Application Layer
2. Presentation Layer
3. Session Layer
4. Transport Layer
5. Network Layer
6. Data Link Layer
7. Physical Layer

Splitting things to layers is very good approach to solve problems but it doesn't mean you have to do all the network operations in network layer.

As you have mentioned, TCP provides feedback to end systems when UDP doesn't but UDP has it's own advantages. First of UDP's datagram is simpler than TCP's one. And also most of huge systems like Facebook uses UDP because using TCP for these kind systems would not be very clever since all the data senders would have to keep track of sending rate, retransmissions rate for many many receivers. So if they've used TCP, their network layer would be under very very big presure.

So they make flow control in the application layer to reduce network traffic.

Comment: Yes, UDP has a lot of advantages over TCP, But my concern was, How people manage the consistency while using UDP.